Power of cosets of normal subgroup
I've seen the below in a paper:

I'm struggling with the $(Nx)(Nx)(Nx) = N$.
We have that $x \not \in N \iff x^{-1} \not \in N$ and by consequence $e \not \in Nx$. Hence $Nx \neq N$.
Also, $(Nx)(Nx)=Nx^2$ leads to $x^2 \in Nx^2$. However, $x \not \in N \iff x^2 \not \in Nx$. Hence, $Nx^2 \neq Nx$. Hence, $Nx^2$ can be the third coset, or $N$.
$(Nx)(Nx)(Nx)=Nx^3$, so $x^3 \in Nx^3$. Clearly, $x^3 \not \in Nx^2$ as $x \not \in N$. Hence $Nx^3 \neq Nx^2$.
At this point I'm not even convinced I have the three cosets. I'm probably going the wrong way about it.
Can someone please clarify this?
Thanks!

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Here $N$ is a normal subgroup of index $3$, so the quotient $G/N$ is a group of order $3$.
Therefore $(Nx)^3 = N$.
(In every finite group $X$, you have $y^{|X|} = 1$ for all $y \in X$.)

D'oh!
Thanks (c:
